# merge cells in gridview that has same value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have data in following format in gridview

```
Region Branch
Gujrat Ahmedabad
Gujrat Surat
Gujrat Vadodara
Mumbai Dadar
Mumbai Andheri
Mumbai Borivali
```

But i want to merge the repeated value like follows

```
Region Branch
Gujrat Ahmedabad
       Surat
       Vadodara
Mumbai Dadar
       Andheri
       Borivali
```

I am taking data from one table to `GridView`. In GridView i have `TemplateField` with Labels which are databound .

Comment: use row data bound event of your grid view or before assigning it to gridview first sort out the repeated values from the data source ( data table )

Comment: I think you looking something like this : **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249155/Rows-and-Columns-Merging-in-ASP-NET-GridView-Contr**

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to set the Label's Text and check if it's the same as the previous:

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex > 0)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
        var rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        int lastRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex - 1;
        var lastRowView = (DataRowView)grid.Rows[lastRowIndex].DataItem;
        // replace Region with the correct column name 
        String region = rowView.Row.Field<String>("Region");
        String lastRegion = lastRowView.Row.Field<String>("Region");
        // replace LblRegion with the correct ID of your Label
        Label label = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LblRegion");
        label.Text = region != lastRegion ? region : "";
    }
}
```