# How to avoid duplicate rows in C# from binded datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

My scenario is simple, but I'm struggling to implement it in coding.

I'm having two tables named film and filmtime. I joined two tables using sql query and bound into gridview from datatable.

Structure of film table is,

```
theatrename     filmname
   max          Spiderman
   well         Godzilla
```

Structure of filmtime table is,

```
theatrename      time
   max           10:00 am
   max           01:00 pm
   max           04:00 pm
   well          11:30 am
```

I want my output as,

```
 theatrename     filmname     time
                              10:00 am
   max            Spiderman   01:00 pm
                              04:00 pm  
   well           Godzilla    11:30 am
```

I used query like this.

```
 SELECT film.theatrename,film.filmname,filmtime.time FROM film  left join filmtime on film.theatrename=filmtime.theatrename
```

By using this query, I am getting result like this,

```
theatrename     filmname     time
   max           Spiderman    10:00 am
   max           Spiderman    01:00 pm
   max           Spiderman    04:00 pm  
   well           Godzilla    11:30 am
```

Any help would be more helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL will return all fields within a row. It's up to you (in this case your c# code) to not show them if they're the same as the previous row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634648/merge-cells-in-gridview-that-has-same-value-in-asp-net possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

What if the theatre "max" has more then one movie ? Can you watch all the movies at the times in the filmtime table ?

---

Well it will allways display the theatrename and the filmname togheter with the time, but you can select the film-names and the theaternames from the film table first and make a second select on the filmtime for each row while creating the GridView where you have the theatrename in the whereclause ...

I think its easier if I show you what I mean.

```
public void FillGridview()
{
    reader = Select * from film;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader2 = Select time from filmtime where theatername = reader["theatername"];
        //add the filmname and the theatrename to the gridview-cells here
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            //add the times to the gridview-cell here (You can start a new line if you want a break with Environment.NewLine()
        }

    }
}
```

Or you just write the theatrename and the filmname into a session, on each new row in the gridview check if its in the session, if yes dont add it into the cell in the new row, if no add it into the cells in the row.

Or check at the [RowDataBound-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) for it and make the label/whatever invisible when its more then once in it.